# Necessary to insulate the ceiling of a conditioned crawlspace

Tags: insulation, crawlspace

I have a new home that does not have insulation in the crawlspace ceilings (the floors throughout the home are above the crawlspace). Is it necessary to insulate the ceiling to prevent heat loss in the winter? The crawlspace is conditioned and has plastic sheeting lining the inside. HVAC is in the crawlspace and it is cool there in the summer.

Answer (score 1):

In a conditioned crawlspace the home and crawlspace are at nearly the same temperature.  The insulation is on the crawlspace walls and “floor”.  The heat loss through the floor will be very small.

Comment: Thank you. My handyman seemed to think it was necessary to isulate the ceiling in the crawlspace. I wonder why.

Comment: @MayDawn -- your handyman is clueless re: conditioned crawlspaces then.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Maybe the handyman would have been the one doing the insulation. In that case he might be less clueless more strapped for work.